# can i get picture of another player in Google Play Games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I want to get another player's profile picture from Google Play Games.
(I know, I can get a picture of a local player in Social Class(unity))

But, I can't find a way to get another player's profile picture.

Can I get the profile picture of a player, who is not one of my friends? 
Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can get that directly. Are you implementing this in a multiplayer scenario?

Comment: Yes. That is needed in the chat system of my game...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way, you can do this directly.
As you are implementing it in multiplayer scenario, this is what I've done before to get other player information:
Whenever, a player connects(in your case in the chat), I send player info(name, image url etc) to all the other players connected in the chat and also, other player's information to the newly connected player. Then load the image locally using `WWW` request in every player.

Comment: Thank you. I could find a way. But, I need a way from Game Center.

Comment: Please let everyone know, if you could find the solution without passing data. It may help many other including me.

Comment: I just use to URL. [http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/USERID?alt=json. => Get field ["entry"]["thumbnail"]["$t"] => https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/~~~~~] It is URL of profile picture.